# Using rsyslog to create different log files for different processes

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

Scenario: I am running a cluster of machines. Each machine runs various python programs with a unique (across the cluster), but dynamically set, ID.

Right now, they are all logging locally. So, I might have logs that look like:

```
process_5.log
process_6.log
```

for processes that had ID's 5 and 6.

Another machine may have:

```
process_20.log
process_25.log
```

I wish to forward these logs to a logserver running rsyslogd.  Python's logging facility has a nice syslog handler, so I understand how I could connect to the remote server.  What I haven't figured out is how to use templating/DynFile to maintain log separation.

e.g. on the logserver, I will want to see:

```
process_5.log
process_6.log
process_20.log
process_25.log
```

which correspond to the logs of the same name on the sending machine.

Is there a way to pull this off with rsyslogd templating?

Comment: Although I'd agree that this question is very very old, it'd still be nice to mark an answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

As the user quanta posted, their template should work.  Here is mine:

```
$template DynFile, "/var/log/syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none            ?DynFile
authpriv.*                                          ?DynFile
mail.*                                              ?DynFile
cron.*                                              ?DynFile
uucp,news.crit                                      ?DynFile
```

This will make logs for each app or facility go into its own file.  Each client's log on the server will appear just like on the client.

Notice the `%syslogfacility-text%`.  You can substitute this part to various other properties per the [Property Replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Each machine runs various python programs with a unique (across the
>   cluster), but dynamically set, ID.

Does the `process_$ID` is also the program name? And if so, try this:

```
$template DynaFile,"/var/log/rsyslog/python_apps/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
if $programname startswith 'process' then -?DynaFile
```

You can put it in separate folder with `%HOSTNAME%` if you want.

PS: I haven't tested. Let me know if it works for you.